# Serial COM just echoes what I send instead of data stream. C#

Tags: c#

I have a thermometer that has an RS232 connection, so I bought U-Port adapter to USB, per the manual you send it the string "Tcrlf" and it starts outputting data. Tried on PuTTy and it works like a charm.
I'm trying to automate some software with the data stream I am getting, however I am having problems communicating it, I have tried a few snippets from various tutorials around the webs but when I send it the same string via my app it just echoes it back and  doesnt stream the data.

This is my Connect Button (after selecting COM port)

```
private void probeConnectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Connect to the NIST-Reference Probe, using Omega HH42 settings:

            if (refProbeCOMPort.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No COM Port selected for NIST-Reference Probe");
                return;
            }
            if (!connectedreferenceProbePort.IsOpen)
            {
                connectedreferenceProbePort.DataBits = HH42DataBits;
                connectedreferenceProbePort.BaudRate = HH42BaudRate;
                connectedreferenceProbePort.PortName = HH42PortName;
                connectedreferenceProbePort.Parity = Parity.None;
                connectedreferenceProbePort.ReadTimeout = 600;
                connectedreferenceProbePort.WriteTimeout = 800;

                connectedreferenceProbePort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                connectedreferenceProbePort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(probeDataReceived);
            }

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to open port");
                if (!connectedreferenceProbePort.IsOpen)
                {
                    connectedreferenceProbePort.Open();
                    if (connectedreferenceProbePort.IsOpen)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Port Opened, sending RTS");
                        connectedreferenceProbePort.RtsEnable = true;
                        connectedreferenceProbePort.WriteLine("Tcrl");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Port is already open");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error opening/writing to Serial Port:: " + ex.Message, "Fatal Error!");
            }
        }
```

That's the connect and "attempting" to start the stream, then I have the datareceived part:
(Per the HH42 manual, after receiving the RTS signal, it sends a ">" character meaning that it's ready to listen).

```
private void probeDataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dataReceived = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Data Incoming");
            connectedreferenceProbePort.DiscardOutBuffer();
            try
            {
                dataReceived = connectedreferenceProbePort.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine("Recevied :" + dataReceived);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());  
            }

            if (dataReceived.Contains(">"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("> Detected, attempting to write Tcrl");
                connectedreferenceProbePort.Write("Tcrl");

            }
        }
```

This is my output from the console and a screenshot of PuttY:[image]

```
Attempting to open port
Port Opened, sending RTS
Data Incoming
Recevied :
> Tcrl
> Detected, attempting to write Tcrl
Data Incoming
Recevied :Tc
Data Incoming
Recevied :rl
```

Comment: Because I can see the word `Tcrl` in your PuTTY window, it is likely that this device uses remote echo.  Which makes receiving the echo of `Tcrl` in your C# code very normal as well.

Comment: Thanks for that, but why does it not start the data stream then? I feel it's my code and not the device since it works in PuttY

Comment: Because you didn't mention that you pressed (ENTER) in PuTTY.... and you didn't do the equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type "Tcrl" and press return in PuTTY, what PuTTY is actually sending are the bytes "T", "c", "r", "l", followed by a carriage return (CR) and a linefeed (NL).

I believe the manual is telling you to send "T", CR, LF, which in C# terms would be the string "T\r\n".